# How do I properly format this string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encoding

I am parsing through a folder of txt files.  These text files have a Dell computer service tag on the second line.  I'd like to grab the second line and eventually place it in a csv spreadsheet.

When I print the service tag to the console read from the txt file it looks fine.  When I put it in a list to be entered into a spreadsheet row, it is formatted incorrectly.  What's going on and how should I be doing this?

```
import glob
import os
#import csv
#fileWriter = csv.writer(open('inventory.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')
#fileWriter.writerow(["Computer Name", "Service Tag"])
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    content = open(filename)
    lines = content.readlines()
    computer_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    service_tag = lines[1]
    row = [computer_name, service_tag]
    print service_tag
    print row
    #fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

Sample output of first file:

```
CBD1WL1

[Computer-PC', '\x00C\x00B\x00D\x001\x00W\x00L\x001\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00\r\x00\n']
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the second string?

Comment: Can you attach your *txt file?

Comment: Do you know what encoding your csv file is using? The issue is likely that Python is assuming the incorrect encoding when it opens the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open your file with the correct encoding. It looks like your file encoded as `utf-16`. You can use [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to read the file with the `utf-16` encoding:

```
import glob
import os
import io
#import csv
#fileWriter = csv.writer(open('inventory.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')
#fileWriter.writerow(["Computer Name", "Service Tag"])
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    content = io.open(filename, encoding='utf-16')
    lines = content.readlines()
    computer_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    service_tag = lines[1]
    row = [computer_name, service_tag]
    print service_tag
    print row
    #fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

I'm pretty confident the encoding is `UTF-16`:

```
>>> a = "blah\nCBD1WL1"
>>> a.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-16')
'\xff\xfeb\x00l\x00a\x00h\x00\n\x00C\x00B\x00D\x001\x00W\x00L\x001\x00'
```

The beginning of a `utf-16`encoded string has a BOM, which is the `\xff\xfeb` part. This would be in the first line of your file, which you throw away in your code. After that, it gets displayed as `\x00<character you expect>`, which is exactly what you have.

Comment: This did it.  Thanks.  I also added .strip() to line 11 to get rid of the extra spaces after the service tag.

Answer (score 2):

So I see null characters in the output of the second string. It looks like these were present in the original file. To remove those use the code below

```
row[1] = row[1].replace('\x00','').strip()
```

gives the output CBD1WL1 which looks maybe like a valid service tag but I can't tell.

Comment: This will work around the issue, but the real problem is that the wrong encoding is being used to open the file.